# Why the last step of Pascal's Identity has been derived so?

Tags: combinatorics

I am studying Pascal's identity but I can't understand how the last step of the equation below is derived.

*Note:* The identity which is being used here is $\dbinom{n}{k}=\dbinom{n-1}{k}+\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$ and in particular this is applied for the first terms in the left of every row.

\begin{array}  \ \dbinom{n}{k} &=\dbinom{n-1}{k}+\dbinom{n-1}{k-1} \\ &=\dbinom{n-2}{k} +\dbinom{n-2}{k-1}+\dbinom{n-1}{k-1} \\ & = \dbinom{n-3}{k}+\dbinom{n-3}{k-1} +\dbinom{n-2}{k-1}
+\dbinom{n-1}{k-1} \\  \end{array}

In the end we have :

$\dbinom{n}{k}=\dbinom{k-1}{k-1}+\dbinom{k}{k-1}+\dbinom{k+1}{k-1}
+\cdots + \dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$

This  last step really confuses me,I can't make sense of it.

By looking at the identity we have used for every beginning term , I would think that the first two binomal coefficients of the last step should have a form like $\dbinom{r-1}{k} +\dbinom{r-1}{k-1}$ ,but I don't have this form so the author must have used something else also...

Can someone help me understand why the last step look so  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write that first term as $\dbinom{k}{k}$, but note that $\dbinom{k}{k} = 1 = \dbinom{k-1}{k-1}$ so the adjustment is made as a nicety to make the lower expression more consistent across the formula.

Comment: Thanks for your response.(Couldn't the author point this at least or is this too trivial lol ?)

Comment: @Mr.Y: I didn't find this initially obvious either, but some others might.